# Resetting the badge value back to 0 after viewing the received notification

Tags: ios, swift

I've been stuck for the past few days trying to increment a `badge` value when it receives a `notification`. I have an observer set up to increment the specified badge value each time a notification is received. It works perfectly fine:

```
//adds the observer. if it goes off then add one to the notification badge
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: PRIVATE_NOTIFICATION, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        //increment a variable
        self.privateBadge += 1

        if let notificationTab = self.tabBar.items?[1]{
            if self.tabBar.selectedItem != notificationTab as UITabBarItem {
        notificationTab.badgeValue = "\(self.privateBadge)"
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            notificationTab.badgeColor = ChatMessageCell.indexedColor
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        }}
    }
```

My issue is trying to get the variable (privateBadge) to reset once the observer is removed.
In `viewDidAppear` on the tab that gets a notification badge, i have a method set up to reset the badge value back to 0 after the user taps that tab:

```
//View Will Appear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Removes the badgeValue and resets messageBadge to 0 in an attempt to start the loop over.
    if let thisTab = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1]{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: PRIVATE_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)
        thisTab.badgeValue = nil
        tabBarControllerClass.privateBadge = 0
    }
}
```

the badgeValue clears as it should but my issue is what happens when I receive another notification. instead of starting over at 0 and incrementing to 1, it picks up where it left off. So for instance, if I receive 2 notifications, the badgeValue will be equal to 2. If I go to that tab with the badgeValue, it clears and should reset back to 0, but it doesn't. Instead, the next time I get a notification, it will say 3 instead of 1.

Are there any better solutions? Should I set up a protocol/delegate system instead?

Comment: Are you sure that tabBarControllerClass.privateBadge & self.privateBadge, these 2 refer to the same variable?

Comment: @Jorora yeah where it says self.privateBadge, its in the Tab bar Controller class. The other is a reference to that class

Comment: You should set the privateBadge variable (the one which is used to show the counter) to 0 and not the other one.

Answer (score 1):

this looks like your bad boy,

```
self.privateBadge += 1
```

you probably forgot to set it back to 0,

```
thisTab.badgeValue = nil
self.privateBadge = 0
```

Not sure if this is possible in your case as I don't see if it is the very same class.

Comment: they're two different classes

Comment: Are you sure tabBarControllerClass.privateBadge and self.privateBadge belongs to the same object? Could you please show how do you get the reference to tabBarControllerClass and show its implementation?