# Using NotificationCenter to set a badge value

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a notification center observer set up in my TabBarController class.
The observer calls a method named setMessageBadge which increments a variable I have set to 0. The purpose of this variable is to serve as the badgeValue for a specific tab bar called MessageController. Whenever the observer is called, the Message Controller tab receives a badgeValue of whatever the variable is at the time until the user selects that tab, then the badgeValue **should** reset.

```
//adds the observer. If it goes off then add one to the message badge and display it.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setMessageBadge), name: MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)


//Sets the badge for the message notifications
func setMessageBadge(){

    //Check message tab
    if let messageTab = self.tabBar.items?[3]{
        //if selected
        if self.tabBar.selectedItem != messageTab as UITabBarItem {
            //Set the message badge value & color
            messageBadge += 1
            messageTab.badgeValue = "\(messageBadge)"
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                messageTab.badgeColor = ChatMessageCell.indexedColor
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }

        //If the messageTab is selected then the messageBadge should be reset to 0
        //But its not. Something with the observer?
        if self.tabBar.selectedItem == messageTab as UITabBarItem  {
            messageBadge = 0
        }
    }

}
```

In the viewWillAppear method of the MessageController tab, I remove the observer, set the badge value equal to nil, and set the variable back equal to 0 from a reference.

```
//View Will Appear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //MessageController TAB
    //Removes the badgeValue and resets messageBadge to 0 in an attempt to start the loop over.
    if let thisTab = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3]{
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)
        thisTab.badgeValue = nil
        tabBarControllerClass.removeMessageBadge()
        print("This is from the tabBarClass: " + "\(tabBarControllerClass.messageBadge)")
    }
}
```

The issue that Im having right now is, whenever the notification gets observed **after** the user clicks the MessageController tab and the badgeValue is set to nil, the variable continues from its last point instead of starting from 0 again even after I set it to 0. For instance, if there are two notifications, the badgeValue should be equal to 2 until the user clicks the screen. When the user clicks the screen, it should be equal to 0. If a user receives another notification, it should start at 0 and go to 1 but instead, it goes to 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting the badge value back to 0 after viewing the received notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704397/resetting-the-badge-value-back-to-0-after-viewing-the-received-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `messageBadge` property in your `UITabBarController` isn't reset at the appropriate time. I assume you want to reset it when the tab is selected. The most straightforward way to do that would be to implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` of your `UITabBarController` (you can just set it to itself). Then, move the code you have that clears out the value into the `didSelect` method of the delegate. It can look something like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                     didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
{
    if self.tabBar.selectedItem == messageTab as UITabBarItem {
        messageBadge = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you so much